# No error, Status 200, yet no data coming into my table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my `set.php`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("rdbms.strato.de", "user", "password", "DBXXXXYYYY");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `defuse_scores` (ip, name, seconds, difficulty, actions) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

$result->bind_param('ssisi', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['seconds'], $_POST['difficulty'], $_POST['actions']);

if (!$result->execute()) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
};

$mysqli->close();
```

Calling the page in a browser returns a blank page and a response status `200 OK` (even though all the `$_POST` stuff supposedly is null).

Calling the page from Postman using POST and this body

```
{ 
  "ip": "127.0.0.119", 
  "name": "ulli", 
  "seconds": "23", 
  "difficulty": "easy", 
  "actions": "22" 
}
```

gives me and empty response and also status `200 OK`.

Yet I don't find any new records in my `defuse_scores` table. What is going on?

I tried adding various lines of code (first three lines) to make any errors visible, yet the page stays blank.

Btw. getting the data works:

http://connexo.de/defuse/defuse-api/get.php

and this is where I'm trying to store using POST:

http://connexo.de/defuse/defuse-api/set.php

This is what my table looks like:

[image: table structure]

Comment: your code has syntax errors

Comment: I cannot find any. Would you mind elaborating on what is wrong?

Comment: Tbh, pointing out syntax errors and not mentioning *what is wrong* is not helpful.

Comment: Where you define the connection to the db you miss a double quote. This is the first error I can see

Comment: Thx, that was an error when I overwrote the real params, which I wasn't planning to publish here. I don't have that in my real code. Fixed in the question now.

Comment: *"Yet I don't find any new records in my defuse_scores table. What is going on?"* - Simple: you never executed the query. But you're probably going to edit your post; again.

Comment: well we can only go in the code posted, regardless of your "real code"

Comment: You still haven't pointed out the syntax errors you mentioned in your initial response. Anything aside the uncloses double quote?

Comment: and your column orders are out of sequence.

Comment: You mean I need to respect the order in the table definition when doing `INSERT INTO \`defuse_scores\` (/* order relevant here?? */)`? I expected the order to be completely irrelevant here, and that I only need to make sure when calling bind_param that parama are in the same order.

Comment: Read the manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php it's all in there, which is something you probably haven't read.

Comment: You have `$result->bind_param(...)` and then check `if (!$result) {`. If the first line didn't throw an error (like `$result` not being an object) then it would be impossible for `$result` to have a falsy value (because it's an object).

Comment: I have replaced `if(!$result)` by `if(!$result->execute())`. Still getting status 200 OK, still no data being stored.

Comment: `execute()` returns whether it succeeded, not whether there were any rows inserted. Check [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/bg/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, it's not num_rows, it's [affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column sequences are off and your query failed *silently*. Why? Because of what you're trying to insert for the IP address is VARCHAR and is in the position used for the `name` column.

The order is important when using the `mysqli_` API, as opposed to PDO using named placeholders doesn't care for the order sequence.

So change your:

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `defuse_scores` (ip, name, seconds, difficulty, actions) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

$result->bind_param('ssisi', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['seconds'], $_POST['difficulty'], $_POST['actions']);
```

to:

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `defuse_scores` (name, seconds, difficulty, actions, ip) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

$result->bind_param('sisis', $_POST['name'], $_POST['seconds'], $_POST['difficulty'], $_POST['actions'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Or using a blank value for the AI'd column which is sometimes needed, and I've seen this happen before:

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `defuse_scores` (id, name, seconds, difficulty, actions, ip) VALUES ('', ?,?,?,?,?)");

$result->bind_param('sisis', $_POST['name'], $_POST['seconds'], $_POST['difficulty'], $_POST['actions'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Another thing that would make your query fail silently, would be a column length not being long enough.

Comment: The column order did not seem relevant. Data is being inserted now, but instead of the values from $_POST it's NULL everywhere except id, ip and timestamp.

Comment: @connexo make sure all POST arrays contain value. Their origins are unknown. I've done my best here. Start re-debugging and use `var_dump()`. Best I can offer. The order *is* relevant  btw.

Comment: @connexo no I haven't. If this is directly related, then I won't be of much help there, sorry.

Comment: It's not, I'm trying to test this using Postman. This is what my Axios post request looks like: `axios.post('https://connexo.de/defuse/defuse-api/set.php', {
        name: 'user',
        seconds: 111,
        difficulty: 'easy',
        actions: 222
      })`. Result is $_POST is an empty Array. Or is $_POST reserved for form submits?

Comment: @connexo I'd like to help you with the Postman stuff, really... but I can't. Far as I know; yes... POST arrays are usually sent via a form with a post method and named inputs to match the post arrays.

Comment: Thanks alot for your patience and support. You brought me one step closer.

Comment: I got it working. The final problem was that Axios by default serializes the data and sends JSON. If you wanna give it a ride: https://connexo.de/defuse/

Comment: @connexo that's great news. Well I for one have learned something here, thanks for sharing that.